# How do I get a conditional type to handle objects that are similar correctly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following type:

```
export type Household = {
  id: string
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
  name: string
}

export type Bucket = {
  id: string
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
  name: string
  ownerId: string
  balance: number
}

export type RawObjectToDoc<Document extends DocType> = Document extends HouseholdDocType
  ? Household
  : Document extends BucketDocType
  ? Bucket
  : never
```

the issue I've run into is that the `Household` type is a subset of `Bucket` so when I run this on a bucket it ends up thinking that the object is a `Household`. Is there a way I can have a bucket be correctly typed as a `Bucket`?

Comment: Check for Bucket first?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when others paste the code into their own IDEs, without unrelated issues like undeclared types (`DateTime`, `DocType`, `currency`, etc).  That will let people test any possible solutions against a common example.

Comment: I see that you edited this but I still don't know what `HouseholdDocType` or `BucketDocType` is and, more importantly, neither does my IDE.  Could you test out your example in some standalone IDE (like the TS Playground) and make sure the only problems shown are the ones you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of some type in the question, I will abstract from the types of the question and show a relevant case. We will have a base type `A` and the type `B`, which extends the `A`. Also, we have type `DocType` that is basically `A` or `B`.

```
type A = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
};

type B = A & {
  isObject: boolean;
};

type DocType = A | B;
```

If we want to check whether a `T extends DocType` is `B` there are two options, first, we check for `T extends B` first, and only after that we check against `T extends A`.

The second option is a bit more complex. In here we will check for the strict equality by using the following type:

```
type isEqual<T, U> = [T] extends [U] ? ([U] extends [T] ? true : false) : false;
```

If `T ⊆ U` and `U ⊆ T` it means that `U = T`. This is basically what this type does.
We can also create the following types to not repeat ourselves too much:

```
type isA<T extends DocType> = isEqual<T, A>;
type isB<T extends DocType> = isEqual<T, B>;
```

Now you can check whether `T` is `A` or `B`.

```
type case1 = isB<A>; // false
type case2 = isB<B>; // true
type case3 = isA<A>; // true
type case4 = isA<B>; // false
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQR4vN)